# Large quantity of data real time visualization

Tags: javascript, mongodb, highcharts, data-visualization, mqtt

I'm building a dashboard receiving tons of data from MQTT in JSON format (data frequency ± 4Hz). I'm trying to visualize this data and initially picked Highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) but quite quickly realized that browser can't simply handle that amount of information.

I'm quite new to visualizing such amounts of data so would appreciate any advice on how to handle that amounts of data (currently arduino's post data to given topics and I receive them on the server, store in mongo and send to the browser to be updated). There's a chance my entire approach is completely wrong so please guide me to a path!

Comment: You might take a look at www.processing.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that the SVG that Highcharts is creating is too large for the browser to handle in a timely manner. If you have too many data points, you'll need to do 1 of 2 things.

1. Switch to a charting library that uses an HTML5 Canvas instead of an SVG
2. Pare down your data using a best fit or some other curve interpolation.

If you switch to a Canvas based chart, you'll lose some of the cool features that SVGs have, but every data point will make it to the page. I've used [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/) for this in the past. It's not free though.

If you pare down your data, not every data point will make it to the page, but the nice features that SVGs allow will still be there. You'll still probably be able to use highcharts.

Comment: Thank you so much! As funny as it sounds I've never even questioned if the data need to be displayed as precisely - as people from machine learning are having raw data anyway so there'd be no loss in data (as server processes mongodb access)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a look at [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) (filtering lib), [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js) (helper library for d3 and crossfilter) they can handle large amount of data well

Answer (score 1):

After using Highcharts for more than 3 years I can recommend it even for the questioned use case. To follow recommendations to use other charting libraries might be not a good choice if you already picked Highcharts (after comparison with others) and invested quite some time in it. If you like it, stick with it.

To address this edge-case with thousands of data points the team announced the [boost.js module](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost).

It originated from [this issue on Github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4093). The discussion reveals lots of background information about the problem domain. And it demonstrates how well the Highcharts team is doing customer-/community-driven development.

Looks like you can do it with Highcharts - if you still want. :-)

Last but not least I can recommend the [Highcharts Cookbook from Packt](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/highcharts-cookbook)

Answer (score 0):

I use grafana to visualise my time series data. I don't believe it supports mongodb at the moment. I use influxdb as the data back end.